# Como puedo utilizar el CASE en un procedimiento sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

Diseñe un procedimiento que según datos de la categoría y el sueldo de un
trabajador, calcule el aumento correspondiente teniendo en cuenta la siguiente
tabla. Imprima la categoría del trabajador y su nuevo sueldo. Utilice case

CATEGORIA: 1 - 2 - 3 - 4
AUMENTO: 15% - 10% - 8% - 7%

```
delimiter //
drop procedure sueldotrabajador//
create procedure sueldotrabajador(in categoria int, sueldo int);
begin

    case
        when categoria='1' then 'sueldo = sueldo * 0.15';
        when categoria='2' then 'sueldo = sueldo * 0.10';
        when categoria='3' then 'sueldo = sueldo * 0.08';
        when categoria='4' then 'sueldo = sueldo * 0.07';
    
end case;
end //
delimiter ;
```

Comment: Claramente se lee un enunciado de una prueba o un deber. Cuál es el error?.

Comment: Podría poner el nombre del profesor que le esta pidiendo esto para remitirnos directamente a él.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La cláusula [`case`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_case.asp) debe ser parte de una sentencia `select` o, en algunos motores, de una asignación de variable.

Por otro lado, de la forma que la tienes escrita devolverá cadenas de texto con la fórmula, pero no el cálculo en si.

Yo escribiría una consulta que devuelva los datos principales y utilizaría `case` solo para determinar el factor a utilizar, por ejemplo:

```
select   t.ID
       , t.Nombres
       , t.Apellidos
       , t.Categoria
       , t.Sueldo as SueldoActual
       , t.Sueldo * (1 +
           case 
             when t.Categoria = '1' then 0.15
             when t.Categoria = '2' then 0.10
             when t.Categoria = '3' then 0.08
             when t.Categoria = '4' then 0.07
           end
         ) as NuevoSueldo
  from trabajador t
```

También podrías escribir todo el cálculo dentro de la clausula `case`, si te queda más claro:

```
select   t.ID
       , t.Nombres
       , t.Apellidos
       , t.Categoria
       , t.Sueldo as SueldoActual
       , case 
           when t.Categoria = '1' then t.Sueldo * 1.15
           when t.Categoria = '2' then t.Sueldo * 1.10
           when t.Categoria = '3' then t.Sueldo * 1.08
           when t.Categoria = '4' then t.Sueldo * 1.07
         end as NuevoSueldo
  from trabajador t
```

En fin, a partir de allí, hay otras docenas de formas de escribir la sentencia, ya es cuestión de gustos.